# Google Sheet API clearing value after updating it

Tags: google-sheets-api

```
def write(self, range, data):
    '''
    clears the spreadsheet, then given a range of data will write that data into the google sheets
    with the id self.spreadsheet_id
    '''
    self.ensure_service_exists()
    self.service.spreadsheets().values().clear(spreadsheetId=self.spreadsheet_id, range='A1:Z4000',
        body={}).execute()
    value_range_body = {'values': data}
    result = self.service.spreadsheets().values().update(spreadsheetId=self.spreadsheet_id,
        range=f'{self.sheet_label}!{range}', valueInputOption=self.value_input_option,
        body=value_range_body).execute()

    return result
```

For some reason, all of my data is being aggregated, and then cleared. When I want the opposite to happen.

Also, does anyone know how to undo a border color change on the API as well?

Answer (score 0):

I found out the answer, I was actually calling it multiple times and therefore deleting the prior data I posted

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar issue :
I have a function in app script using Sheets API to updates some ranges on a sheet (actually copying value from one sheet to one other).

The function works well except that all updated values get cleared at function exit :

```
function ShadowCourses() {
  const sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("BilanCourse");
  const targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("CourseShadow");
  var SSid = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
  sourceSheet.getRange('H13').setValue(SSid)
  var rangeName1 = 'BilanCourse!C2:C300';
  var rangeName2 = 'BilanCourse!G2:G300';
  var rangeName3 = 'BilanCourse!I2:I300';
  var rangeName4 = 'BilanCourse!M2:M300';
  var nb_valRO = targetSheet.getRange(1, 25).getValue();
  var nb_valIO = targetSheet.getRange(2, 25).getValue();
  var nb_valRS = targetSheet.getRange(1, 26).getValue();
  var nb_valIS = targetSheet.getRange(2, 26).getValue();
  const sourLR = Math.max(nb_valRO,nb_valIO)
  const targLR = Math.max(nb_valRS,nb_valIS)
  const MLR = Math.max(sourLR,targLR)
  targetSheet.getRange(2,1,MLR,6).clearContent()
  sourceSheet.getRange('H13').setValue('Anciennes valeurs effacées')
  const SS = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchGet(SSid,{ranges: [rangeName1, rangeName2, rangeName3, rangeName4]}).valueRanges;
  var sRecettes = SS[0].values;
  var sAttribR = SS[1].values;
  var sIngred = SS[2].values;
  var sAttribI = SS[3].values;
  var trangeName1 = 'CourseShadow!A2:A'+(sRecettes.length+1).toString();
  var trangeName2 = 'CourseShadow!B2:B'+(sAttribR.length+1).toString();
  var trangeName3 = 'CourseShadow!E2:E'+(sIngred.length+1).toString();
  var trangeName4 = 'CourseShadow!F2:F'+(sAttribI.length+1).toString();
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update({values: sRecettes}, SSid, trangeName1,{valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED"});
  sourceSheet.getRange('H13').setValue('Noms recettes sauvés')
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update({values: sAttribR}, SSid, trangeName2,{valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED"});
  sourceSheet.getRange('H13').setValue('Attribution recettes sauvée')
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update({values: sIngred}, SSid, trangeName3,{valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED"});
  sourceSheet.getRange('H13').setValue('Nom igrédients sauvés')
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update({values: sAttribI}, SSid, trangeName4,{valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED"});
  sourceSheet.getRange('H13').setValue('Attribution ingrédients sauvée');
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+2", "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm");
  sourceSheet.getRange('H13').setValue('Attribution sauvée - '+date);
  rg = sourceSheet.getRange('H3').uncheck();
};
```